# Chat - No change in content counts as an edit

Tags: feature-request, chat, revisions-list

In chat, I sometimes end up accidentally editing a past message, and the easiest way I find to do this is by pressing <kbd>Enter</kbd>.

What I noticed is that chat edits that contain no changes from the last revision are still counted as edits.  See [this revision history](https://chat.stackexchange.com/messages/6003690/history) for an example of what I mean.

This is not exactly a bug, but it is just something that may want to be changed.  Currently you can generate countless message revisions (which I believe all have to be saved in the database) with no change in content.

Comment: FYI, pressing ESC will stop editing without submitting.

Comment: OK, thanks.  I was also suggesting a possible check that could be ran before submitting an edit.

Comment: Is this even a problem? No offense, but what can we achieve by fixing this bug?

Comment: @nhaht I've really confused people in chat when they try to figure out what, if anything, changed.

Comment: @simchona: +1 Fair enough.